# How do I create a sliding team section with variable positioning and z-indexes?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

In Wordpress, I am trying to create a team section that simulates what CapitalG has on their website. I am thinking of using jQuery to do this and dynamically set the z-indexes such that I can hover over each team member and have their name and title show up below each member.

Example of this is Capital G's team page: https://capitalg.com/team/

Here's an image of what they're currently doing:[image: Team slider with buttons to left and right and hover functionality over each member displaying name and title]

Each one of the images is currently a transparent .png file.

I've tried setting the z-index dynamically and adding the CSS hover functionality over each member as a parameter but having trouble getting the positioning right and the images to overlap.

I expect the output of this to look like the team slider for CapitalG but the actual output currently looks like images next to each other. Do I have to use absolute positioning for this?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: zIndex is for making HTML elements stack on top of each other.  HTML and CSS have a basic and simple slider mechanism built in [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp).  The zIndex feature is great for popup windows [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)...  I have not looked at the code behind capitalG yet, but I will.

Comment: P.S.  I'm on my cell phone right now - and am unable to see the page source of CapitalG - but it just looks like an HTML divider with images next to each other.  NOTE1: png image format allows for "clear" or "translucent" parts of an image - and as you can see, the white-background portion of these people's pictures never over lap their forground.  NOTE2: They seem to "step aside" when one of the people in this photo is centered.  That means JavaScript to move the individual photos left and right. NOTE3: zIndex works great, keep it simple.